# Implicit method for two coupled PDEs

Tags: pde, matrix, nonlinear-equations

I have two equations (coupled), with the variables $T_1$ and $T_2$ and the constant $T_0$, which are (when written unitless, i.e. without prefactors):
$$\partial_t T_1 = 1-T_1^3+T_1+\nabla\left(\frac{1}{T_2^{2.5}+T_2^{2.4}}\right)\nabla T_1+\frac{1}{T_2^{2.5}+T_2^{2.4}}\nabla^2T_1$$
and
$$ \partial_tT_2=\left(\frac{T_1}{1+T_1^2}\left(T_0-T_2\right)+\nabla\left(\frac{1}{1+T_2+T_2^2}\right)\nabla T_2+\frac{1}{1+T_2+T_2^2}\nabla^2T_2\right)$$
Now my usual approach is to divide such equations into a linear and a nonlinear term, as for the first equation:
$$\partial_t T_1 = \underbrace{1-T_1^3+T_1}_{\text{Nonlinear}}+\underbrace{\nabla\left(\frac{1}{T_2^{2.5}+T_2^{2.4}}\right)\nabla T_1+\frac{1}{T_2^{2.5}+T_2^{2.4}}\nabla^2T_1}_{\text{Linear}}$$
and then splitting the linear term up into $T_{x,0}$ and $T_{x,1}$ for the current and next step, as for a reduced equation
$$\begin{split}
\partial_tT_1&=\nabla T_1\\
&\Rightarrow\\
\frac{T_{1,1}-T_{1,0}}{dt}&=\frac{\nabla T_{1,1}+\nabla T_{1,0}}{2}\\
\left(\frac{1}{dt}-\nabla\right)T_{1,1}&=\left(\frac{1}{dt}+\nabla\right)T_{1,0}
\end{split}$$
which then can be solved using a matrix approach and -solver. In order to extend it to $T_2$, I can create a vector of both variables, such that 
$$\vec{A}\begin{pmatrix}
T_{1,1}\\
T_{2,1}
\end{pmatrix}=\vec{B}\begin{pmatrix}
T_{1,0}\\
T_{2,0}
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
\text{Nonlinear}_{T_1}\\
\text{Nonlinear}_{T_2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
But now I am stuck how to do that for 
$$\nabla\left(\frac{1}{T_2^{2.5}+T_2^{2.4}}\right)\nabla T_1$$
Of course I can split it up to
$$\begin{split}
\nabla\left(\frac{1}{T_2^{2.5}+T_2^{2.4}}\right)&=\frac{\nabla\left(\frac{1}{T_{2,1}^{2.5}+T_{2,1}^{2.4}}\right)+\nabla\left(\frac{1}{T_{2,0}^{2.5}+T_{2,0}^{2.4}}\right)}{2}
\end{split}$$
but then I do not know how to integrate it into the matrix equations, after I do not know how to create a matrix $\vec{C}$, such that
$$
\vec{C}\cdot T_2=\nabla\left(\frac{1}{T_2^{2.5}+T_2^{2.4}}\right)
$$
Is there such a matrix? Or is my whole approach skewed, and should be rethought?

Comment: Why do you call it a linear term if it depends nonlinearly on $T_2$? I think you can linearize this operator (and all the other nonlinear things) by taking there $T_2$ from the previous (already computed) time layer. Or you can linearize more accurately, introducing the Jacobian.

Comment: Can you give an example for that?

Comment: Would method of line be a possible option? I like it a lot because you only have to worry about the spacial discretisation and let the ODE solver take care of the time-domain.

Answer (score 1):

Linearization of nonlinear PDEs is usually done by using the Frechet derivative of the system.
First, let us define $T=\left(\begin{array}{c}T_1\\T_2\end{array}\right)$.
Then, in your coupled system you can always replace $T_1=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\end{array}\right)T$ and $T_2=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\end{array}\right)T$ and write it as a coupled system:

$$\partial_tT= F(T)$$.
Now, you are looking for the frechet derivative of $F$. $$F_T\Delta:=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{F(T+\epsilon\Delta)-F(T)}{\epsilon}$$.